# firefox removes cookies automatically

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, cookies

I use some proxy software. When I login to some sites, if I change proxy settings, firefox removes my cookies and I must login again. It occurs on every site. Also when I close firefox and open it again, I should login to sites even if I chose *remember me* option on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `Proxy Selector` add-on that made firefox delete cookies. In default preferences of this plugin, every time proxy changes, firefox must clean cookies. Change it and cookies will be OK.